# Get elements with same key but different value in two PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

So i get info from a JSON file and i get one array called "items" and pass it to this array in PHP:

```
"items": [
{
  "id": "2",
  "parent": null,
  "itemType": 0,
  "title": "Manuel Perez",
  "description": "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
  "phone": "(491) 183-55-45",
  "email": "ste.ballmer@name.com",
  "photo": "",
  "image": "demo/images/photos/m.png",
  "href": "showdetails.php?recordid=2",
  "isVisible": true
}
```

Then i have to compare this with another that can contain more or less items, but i can take those elements that change the size of the array. But when i want to get the difference when the size is the same and a value of a key is different when i cant make it work.

If in the second array in the position 2 the value of "itemType" change to 1 i want to get somenthing like this:

```
Array[2] - > "itemType": 1
```

And so that way i can know if something changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two arrays $items1 and $items2:

```
$items1 = [
    "id" => "2",
    "itemType" => 0,
];

$items2 = [
    "parent" => null,
    "itemType" => 1,
];
```

To get the things that are added or modified in $items2 compared to $item1, you can use:

```
array_diff_assoc($items2, $items1) // displays ['parent' => null, 'itemType' => 1]
```

To get the things that are added or modified in $items1 compared to $item2, you can use:

```
array_diff_assoc($items1, $items2) // displays ['id' => "2", 'itemType' => 0]
```

If you want both, you can combine these two arrays and use them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all covert your JSON data into Array and take items form both into $jsonArray1 and $jsonArray2 respectively.
2. Now sort your both array by key like this
   ksort($jsonArray1);
   ksort($jsonArray2);
3. Now take difference of both array
   $diffData = array_diff_assoc($jsonArray1, $jsonArray2);

Output: $diffData is your output, hope this will help!!